# Evaluate stringified json having interpolatable value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose variable `b=2` and a stringified json

```
j = '{"b": "#{b}", "c": null}'
```

The desired result is:

```
{
  "b" => "2",
  "c" => nil
}
```

My observation:

Since json string contains null, we **can not eval** it because ruby will say **undefined variable or method** `null`. Also, I don't want to replace `null` with `nil`.

The only option left is to parse and evaluate. 
So I tried the following:

```
eval(JSON.parse(j).to_s)
```

which results to

```
{
    "b" => "\#{b}"
}
```

Please help to achieve desired result?

Comment: I think `j` is invalid, as it closes right after the `b` value. Was it a typo?

Comment: It was a type, I have updated.

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this: `j = "{'b': '#{b}', 'c': null}"`

UPDATE:

Sorry. It should be like this

```rb
b = 2
JSON.parse("{ \"b\": \"#{b}\", \"c\": null }")
```

Comment: In this case, `j` becomes `"{'b': '2', 'c': null}"` which is a string, how to parse it as json?

Comment: j is not stringified json here.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "stringified json".  Your desired output can be achieved using the solution above. If you want to render it as json, you can use `render json: JSON.parse("{ \"b\": \"#{b}\", \"c\": null }")`

Comment: `'{"b": "#{b}", "c": null}'` data comes from third party, its not formed by my code.

Comment: The above data comes for third party and after assignment to a var it becomes `"{\"b\": \"\#{b}\", \"c\": null}"` . Which not same as you have mentioned.

Comment: That's why you need to parse it using JSON.parse(j). After that you can get the value of `b` by doing ` var['b']. Assuming you assign the parsed json to variable var